# ¿Cómo puedo escribir en un fichero .txt datos que no se repitan?

Tags: java, java-8

estoy intentando escribir un fichero. Hasta ahora lo he conseguido pero no quiero que me escriba en el .txt datos que se repitan. Os paso el código:

```
            //creamos un fichero
            File fichero = new File("target/rerun.txt");
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("target/rerun.txt", true);
            // si existe el fichero, solo escribira el txt
            if (fichero.exists()) {
                    System.out.println("existe");
                        writer.write(result);
                        writer.close();
                    
    
                } else {
                //si no existe, creará uno nuevo para escribir en el txt
                    System.out.println("nuevo");
                    fichero.createNewFile();
                        writer.write(result);
                        writer.close();
                }
```

En el resultado muestra datos fallidos, solo quiero que muestren sin repetirse, como podría hacerlo?

Comment: Recorrer el archivo línea por línea buscando el texto. ¿? Esa no fue la primera idea que tuviste?

Comment: Si, lo unico que nose como controlar que no escriba más cuando lo encuentre